# ListView item link click state of row with button inside list item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

How can I link the "clicks" on the list item row shot#1 with clicks on radiobutton within the row shot#2.

At the moment it is: Clicking on the row will show the "focus" hilight but will not trigger the radiobutton selection, clicking on the RB will "check" radiobutton but will not give "hilight" effect.

But I would like to have it working as one: "Clicking on row will show focus and do selection on RB and clicking on RB will check radiobutton and hilight row".

Is there a way to achieve this? With this setup, I think I could just change the row so it is a radiobutton not contains radiobutton.

I have a custom ArrayAdapter to handle radiobutton clicks (and handling "groups" of radiobuttons).

**shot#1**

[image: list item selected]

**shot#2**

[image: list item radiobutton selected]

**list view xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_radiolist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/radiobutton_list_item" >
</ListView>
```

**row xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/filterlist_sub_header_pad_left"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/filterlist_sub_header_pad_right" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_option"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Not marked favourite" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I did temporarily is:
I set the RadioButton's clickable to false.
In ArrayAdapter, instead on RB I set clickListener on the row view (based on view type).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have clear idea about what you want to do. Could you please explain it bit more? What is RB stands for and about two screen shots of lists, are they same or two separate lists? what is the relationship you need between rows in two lists.

Comment: RB - is short for **R** adio **B** utton.
2 Screenshots shows the same list (containing different types of rows). And shows results of clicking in different part of RB row. First shows hilighted row but not selected RB, second shows selected RB but no row hilight.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to accomplish this is to use CheckedTextView in your row.xml. By default android provides the behavior you asking in layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice. But the radio button will be right aligned. If you want the radio button to be left aligned you will have to customize [simple_list_item_single_choice](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/414051b8b1e31b69ca622d68f391245f1989500b/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_single_choice.xml) i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.-->

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

you need to just reposition the listChoiceIndicator to the left by making drawing it on the left side instead of the default right. Similarly you can adapt the multiple Choice item for same behavior.

Comment: putting the code here so that users can refer to it even if the link becomes unavailable

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply programmatically check the RadioButton in the `OnItemClicklistener` of the `ListView` and vice versa?

So for example,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

              // set the RadioButton of the corresponding
             // view that was clicked by invoking setChecked(true) 
            // on that RadioButton;

        }
});
```

Then, similarly call `setSelected(true)` on your `View` that contains the `RadioButton` within the `OnCheckedChangeListener` in your `onCheckedChanged` implementation of the `RadioGroup`.

Comment: Do you know about any other routes? With this I have to make onItemClick on each ListView with this row layouts and need to know to call selection methods. In addition I have to add code to do the hilighting of the background item from the click listener of radiobutton. I want something self-contained.

Comment: Not sure how else it can be done, sorry - I've never had to do something like this before so I'm not sure what would be the best way. I realize this may be a long solution to implement; hopefully someone will find something better.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a row as a radio button, rather than creating a custom radio element yourself. Then the events will be directly passed to radio button.

Refer for details : http://rudisss.blogspot.in/2012/10/listview-with-radio-buttons-and.html

Comment: In question I've mentioned that it is not a solution, i.e. I could have more than radio button in it. or my design requires this additional "container" e.g. for margins which otherwise would be applied on RB.

Answer (score 1):

As of your current design we can simply implement this requirement with a RadioButton . For achieving this  simply remove the RelativeLayout outside the Radiobutton in row layout and make RadioButon as the parent of row layout. And write a customized selector for the RadioButton. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Any examples of the customized selector for the RadioButton? Setting RadioButton as row is not a solution as I'm not able to apply margins properly (it doesnt move the radiobutton icon but increase the space between rb icon and text)

Comment: If you interested in Custom RadioButton you can go for that .